# AKKA.NET : is possible to create unique actor on multiple running applications?

Tags: asp.net-core, akka.net, akka-cluster

I am building a **Asp.net Core** api and it's will be running on multiples servers instances, My probleme is to ensure to create unique Actors in all running aplications using **AKKA.NET** and sending a messages to this actors from other instances.

Is like a distributed cache where we have the same value for all instances.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?  Distributed data(CRDT) https://getakka.net/articles/clustering/distributed-data.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use akka.net [routers](https://getakka.net/articles/actors/routers.html). You should configure cluster of asp.net machines, and define router(there are a lot built in) with required strategy(Broadcast as i understand your needs), then, for any message sended at routee path, it will be broadcasted to all actors in the group.